# jquery on click not working with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show some text when I push a button, it's simple, but it doesn't work to me :(. This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="form">
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="button" value="Buscar" id="search" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="contenido">some content</div>
```

and this is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contenido').hide();
    $("#search").on('click', function(e){
        mostrar();
    });

});

    var mostrar=function(e){
        $("#contenido").show(2500);
    }
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work"? What is happening (or not happening)? Are there any errors?

Comment: It works, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54q3k/), just copy-pasted as is

Comment: Works fine on Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/WDx7C/

Comment: check the error in your browser console

Comment: @RenatoZannon nothing happens

Comment: That examples on jsfiddle doesn't work to me..., and this is whay I get from the brownser console: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle of your own that shows the problem?

Comment: @Doruko The event.returnValue deprecated can be fixed by using the latest version of jQuery.  You can ignore that warning for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8EzYB/)

Do you have `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` in your html?

Comment: It's solved, I don't know how, but in someway, a file called "functionns.js" instead of "functions.js" was created magically, and i was editing "functionns.js. Kill me please.

Answer (score 0):

did you try html() instead of show(). Also, try putting in same scope

Answer (score 0):

should be under the same scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contenido').hide();
    $("#search").on('click', function(e){
        mostrar();
    });

    function mostrar(e){
      $("#contenido").show(2500);
    }
});
```

Comment: i have other codes in my way, and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var mostrar=function(e) {
    $("#contenido").show(2500);
}
```

For this:

```
function mostrar(e) {
    $("#contenido").show(2500);
}
```

Or move the `var` declaration to top!

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contenido').hide();
$("#search").click('click', function(e){
    mostrar();
});

var mostrar=function(e){
    $("#contenido").show(2500);
}
});


</script>
```

and add reference to js if you don't have it;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the .on() function to .bind() and it will work.

> As of jQuery version 1.7, the on() method is the new replacement for
>   the bind(), live() and delegate() methods. This method brings a lot of
>   consistency to the API, and we recommend that you use this method, as
>   it simplifies the jQuery code base.

Check your jQuery Version and make sure it is up to date..:)
Meanwhile, Happy Coding